# Box Select Edit mode not selecting all

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Blender 3.0/Windows 11
Have copied a bunch of “planks”, rotated, scaled, .... them.
More than one Object selected when i go into Edit mode.
When i wanted to extend the ends of all of them this happens.
Edit mode, Box select left ends of all. Right end of one of them gets selected.  Noted that 2nd/3rd from the bottom are same just rotated.

Not sure why

Appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you duplicated the objects, you must of pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> which duplicates and links object data. To separate the object data so they can be edited separately. Select the objects that are linked, go to Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks you that is it.